# Finding solution set of a Linear equation?

Tags: c++, python, c, algorithm, math

I need to find all possible solutions for this equation:

`x+2y = N`,  `x<100000` and `y<100000`.

given `N=10`, say.

I'm doing it like this in *python*:

```
for x in range(1,100000):
    for y in range(1,100000):
        if x + 2*y == 10:
             print x, y
```

How should I optimize this for **speed**? What should I do?

Essentially this is a **Language-Agnostic** question. A *C/C++* answer would also help.

Comment: Do you require that the answer is a natural number?

Comment: "Optimize" against what measure? Correctness? Readability? Re-usability?

Comment: Optimize for **Speed.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lefteris E](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15882156/2032663) 's answer is the way to go,

but I do feel `y` should be in the range `[1,N/2]` instead of `[1,2*N]`

Explanation:

```
x+2*y = N

//replace x with N-2*y
N-2*(y) + 2*y = N
N-2*(N/2) + 2*y = N
2*y = N

//therefore, when x=0, y is maximum, and y = N/2
y = N/2
```

So now you can do:

```
for y in range(1,int(N/2)):
   x = N - (y<<1)
   print x, y
```

Answer (score 5):

if `x+2y = N`, then `y = (N-x)/2` (supposing `N-x` is even). You don't need to iterate all over `range(1,100000)`

like this (for a given N)

```
if (N % 2): x0 = 1
else: x0 = 0
for x in range(x0, min(x,100000), 2):
    print x, (N-x)/2
```

EDIT:
you have to take care that N-x does not turn negative. That's what `min` is supposed to do

The answer of Leftris is actually better than mine because these special cases are taken care of in an elegant way

Comment: Could you please update this answer with a little bit extra explanation? Kind of didn't get the point completely. Sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 3):

we can iterate over the domain of y and calculate x. Also taking into account that x also has a limited range, we further limit the domain of y as [1, N/2] (as anything over N/2 for y will give negative value for x)

```
x=N;
for y in range(1,N/2-1):
     x = x-2
     print x, y
```

- This just loops N/2 times (instead of 50000)
- It doesn't even do those expensive multiplications and divisions

Comment: I think this is the quickest existing solution and still elegant.

Comment: Is it possible to do any further optimization? :)

Comment: Shouldn't y be in the range [1,N/2]?

Comment: I don't know about Python, but in C++, using bit shifting will only serve to obfuscate; it won't make the program any faster.  (I'd actually be surprised if it makes a measurable difference in speed in Python, either.)

Comment: yes sorry N/2. I actually had it N/2 originally :p. yes it can be optimized more. If you notice x in the loop is always decremented by 2 . you could initially set x = N, and in the loop just do x = x - 2, which gets rid of the multiplication all togeather

Answer (score 1):

This runs in quadratic time.  You can reduce it to linear time by rearranging your equation to the form `y = ...`.  This allows you to loop over `x` only, calculate `y`, and check whether it's an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to only examine even numbers for `x` given `N =10`;
the reason is that: `2y` must be even, therefore, `x` must be even. This should reduce the total running time to half of examining all `x`.

If you also require that the answer is natural number, so negative numbers are ruled out. you can then only need to examine numbers that are even between `[0,10]` for `x`, since both `x` and `2y` must be not larger than `10` alone.